# How to enable the mic for a bluetooth headset?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, microphone, zoom-meeting, voip

Where is the mic for a [bog standard](https://www.poly.com/us/en/support/product/voyager-5200) plantronics plt v5200 bluetooth headset?

The speaker test:

[image: zoom]

works fine.

There's no option to select a mic, however.

In bluetooth settings, the options are sparse to say the least:

[image: headset]

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 2a7a:6a18 CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo dmesg | grep snd
[   21.324288] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   21.565701] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC269VB: SKU not ready 0x411111f0
[   21.566011] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC269VB: line_outs=1 (0x1b/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   21.566016] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   21.566019] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   21.566021] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   21.566023] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   21.566025] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Rear Mic=0x19
[   21.566027] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Front Mic=0x18
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ uname -a
Linux mordor 5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 23:06:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

pactl:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ pactl list cards
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 23
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xe1a60000 irq 32"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "1c20"
        device.product.name = "6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 39268, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5965, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 865, available: no)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (type: Line, priority: 9000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (type: HDMI, priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
            Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo, output:hdmi-surround71, output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo

Card #1
    Name: bluez_card.F4_B6_88_10_87_E4
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 24
    Properties:
        device.description = "PLT V5200 Series"
        device.string = "F4:B6:88:10:87:E4"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_F4_B6_88_10_87_E4"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "PLT V5200 Series"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: headset_head_unit
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
        headset-input: Headset (type: Headset, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

---

installed `pipewire` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1247209/847449), so:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ systemctl --user restart pipewire
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 34
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 44
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: nicholas
Host Name: mordor
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.33)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
Cookie: 3e8a:5969
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

see also:

[Bluetooth Headphones switches from (A2DP sink) to (HSP/HFP) when starting VoIP application](https://askubuntu.com/q/1085480/847449)

[How to use a bluetooth headset mic in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/605075/847449)

https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/bluetooth-headset-cant-set-output-as-a2dp-sink-while-using-the-mic-as-input-device/3944/6