# earbuds in mono

Tags: microphone, bluetooth-speaker

i just followed the steps on [Microphone not working on Bluetooth earbuds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247209/microphone-not-working-on-bluetooth-earbuds) and it works now, I got the mic working.

Installed pipewire and all, but still get no stereo sound.

Does anyone have found a solution?

I'm on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You do not get stereo sound and mic at the same time. A search of the site would have given you this link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280768/bluetooth-headset-only-plays-sound-in-mono

Comment: But how does this work in stereo with my smartphone? This is a driver limitation.

Comment: I know nothing about your phone I answered about Ubuntu.